# I dont understand why "Call to undefined method CI_Input()::event()" is being thrown

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I am trying to use a form to add a new record, in this case for an event, to a database. I dont understand why I am recieving the following error:

This is my create function in my controller, 'Events.php':

```
    public function create(){
        $data['title'] = 'Create Event';

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('location', 'Location', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('date', 'Date', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('time', 'Time', 'required');

        if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('events/create', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        } else {
            $this->Event_model->create_event();
            redirect('events');
        }

    }
```

and then this is my create_event function in my 'Event_model' to try and create a new entry object(?) and then add it to the database:

```
    public function create_event(){
            $slug = url_title($this->input->event('title'));

            $data = array(
                'title' => $this->input->event('title'),
                'description' => $this->input->event('description'),
                'date' => $this->input->event('date'),
                'time' => $this->input->event('time'),
                'location' => $this->input->event('location'),
                'slug' => $slug,
                'invitees' => $this->input->event('invitees')
            );

            return $this->db->insert('events', $data);
        }
```

I am being given the error:

```
Message: Call to undefined method CI_Input::event()
```

from the first time I try and call 'event' in the `create_event()` function when I am trying to assign the `$slug` value.

I understand that I have not initialized 'event' in the create function as an object(or method?) before I am trying to refer to it, but I am only trying to fetch the values from the form and pass them to the database,

In the guide I am following they receive no such error

Any help would be hugely appreciated

Comment: Can you do a var_dump($this->input); before assigning $slug? see if you have any info in it?

Comment: Also, try $this->input->post('event') instead of $this->input->event

Answer (score 0):

There is no `event()` method in [Input class](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/input.html#id7). You should use `post()` or `get()` methods.

```
'title' => $this->input->post('title')
```

Comment: Thankyou, I now understand what I have done wrong in this situation :)